# How to execute common code after a Dojo Deferred object is resolved or rejected?

Tags: javascript, dojo, promise, deferred

I have a question about dojo/Deferred.  I'll start with the question, then go into more detail about what I'm doing:

Is there a way to execute the same lines of code regardless of the outcome of the deferred, sort of like a `finally` block in a `try...catch` statement?  From what I've read, it doesn't seem like there is, but maybe I'm understanding the documentation wrong and wanted to verify that with the SO community.

Here's what I'm doing:

In Dojo 1.9 (also works in 1.8), I instantiate a dojox.widget.Standby (a loading overlay) for a ContentPane before loading some data.  Once the deferred call has completed, I want to hide my overlay as shown below:

```
standby = new Standby({
    ... // standby props
});
this.addChild(standby);
standby.show();

queryResults = grid.store.query({
    ... // query props
});
queryResults.then(function (results) {
    if (results) {
        ... // do something
    }

    standby.hide();
}, function (error) {
    ... // handle error

   standby.hide();
});
```

This works fine; however, presumably, I could have some process to be implement after the deferred completes that takes up several lines of code instead of just a single line and I wouldn't want to duplicate those lines of code.  An alternative would be to create a private function and just call it with a one-liner in each block, but if there's a better way, I'd rather take that route.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [always](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/promise/Promise.html#always) method of the Promises API to execute a function regardless of whether the underlying `Deferred` succeeds or fails.

```
queryResult
   .then(onSuccess, onFailure)
   .always(function() {
      standby.hide();
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question. A `dojo/Deferred` object will return another Deferred object when `Deferred#then` is called. This allows you to chain a differed with multiple callbacks that are fired in a serial order. Therefore, I believe you can do something like this:

```
queryResults.then(function (results) {
   if (results) {
       ... // do something
   }
}, function (error) {
    ... // handle error
}).then(function(data){
    // This will be fired with data returned from the previous callback.
    standby.hide();
});
```

You can [see this example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W8T6N/3/) that illustrates a similar, albeit simple, use case where regardless of if the Deferred is rejected or resolved, the callback to the second `Deferred#then` is fired after the initial error/success callback.

Comment: both you and @Lucas have answered my question since both of your answers are correct.  I gave the 'Best Answer' to @Lucas because I think that `always` represents a clearer intent than an additional `then`.  But I up-voted your answer for its correctness.

Answer (score -1):

```
var deferred = new Deferred(); 
deferred.promise.always( function() { alert('ciao'); } );
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything over the existing answers.

Comment: yes it does, deffered extends promise, so i use the promise property without having to call the .then() function and set the callback functions.

Comment: The other answers use `.then()` because the OP needs those outcome-dependent callback functions as well.

Comment: the exact question is "Is there a way to execute the same lines of code regardless of the outcome of the deferred, sort of like a finally block in a try...catch statement?" no mention of then()